# Create multiple tables by cycling through a query

Tags: php, mysql, loops

Here is my current code:
    $varVeh=$_POST['Veh_num'];

```
$sql_HiScores = "SELECT 
     c.course_name as course,
     e.distance as distance, e.score as score,
     e.time as time, e.user as User
   FROM hc_entries e
   LEFT JOIN hc_course c on e.course=c.course_num
   WHERE e.vehicle=$varVeh
   ORDER BY course, score DESC";

$result_HiScores = mysql_query($sql_HiScores);

$sql_vehName="SELECT Veh_name FROM hc_vehicle_type WHERE Veh_num=$varVeh ";
$result_vehName = mysql_query($sql_vehName);
$vehName=mysql_fetch_assoc($result_vehName);

echo "<table><tr><th>Best Scores for ".$vehName['Veh_name']."</th></tr></table>";
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><th>Course</th><th>Score</th><th>Distance</th><th>Player</th><th>Time</th></tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_HiScores))
{
    echo "<tr>";  
    echo "<td>" .$row['course'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['score'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['distance'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['User'] . "</td>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

What I think I have to do is create a query that selects * from e.course that builds an array. Then cycle through the existing query with the array results. Finally, I would like to display individual tables for each  course and limit it to the top 5 results for each course.

Can anyone confirm or deny my logic, and point me in a direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't be using the mysql_ functions, they're deprecated.  At the least, you should switch to [mysqli_](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (a pretty easy switch), or better, learn how to use [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).  It's a bit different and more involved to switch, but your code will be better and safer for it.

With that out of the way: your logic is pretty accurate.  Limiting your results to the top 5 results *for each course* in one query isn't something that's easily done with SQL to my knowledge, so your plan is good: query a list of courses, then cycle through them with your existing query, running it once for each course, with a LIMIT 5 to get the top 5.

You might as well keep the table generation within this loop as well, since it's a table-per-course.  You'd want to move the VehName query out of the loop, since you only need to run that once.

Also, some unsolicited PHP advice: any text outside of the  tags will just be output directly, so take advantage of its built-in-templating and [alternative syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) to make your table generation code nicer:

```
<?php
   /* Gather your data here... */
?>
<table>
  <tr><th>Best Scores for <?php echo $vehName['Veh_name'] ?></th></tr>
</table>
<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <th>Course</th>
    <th>Score</th>
    <th>Distance</th>
    <th>Player</th>
    <th>Time</th>
  </tr>
  <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_HiScores)): ?>
  <tr>  
    <td><?php echo $row['course'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['score'] ?></td>";
    <td><?php echo $row['distance'] ?></td>";
    <td><?php echo $row['User'] ?></td>";
  </tr>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

put the entire table html inside the while loop and add 'LIMIT 5' to the end of your query