# foreach loop from mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

Coming back to my project after putting it down for a while: [Cycling through a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19598904/create-multiple-tables-by-cycling-through-a-query).

I understand that the below code can be cleaned up (PHP usage and table arrangement) and that MySQL commands are deprecated. ( I am working on that part).

But I can't see why I can't make this work. The `print_r()`  gives `Resource ID #5` error.  My results show 2 tables, each with identical results all from the same course. I am expecting 8 tables, each table with a different course.

Should I use a `while` loop? if so how? I realize this is elementary, but this is still all new to me so please be gentle.

```
<?php

include 'inc.php';

$varVeh=$_POST['Veh_num'];
$sql_course="select course_num from hc_course";
$results_course=mysql_query($sql_course);

print_R($results_course);

foreach(mysql_fetch_array($results_course) as $rc)
{
    $sql_HiScores = "SELECT c.course_name as course,  e.distance as distance, e.score as score, e.time as time, e.user as User from hc_entries e left join hc_course c on e.course=c.course_num WHERE c.course_num=$rc and e.vehicle=$varVeh ORDER BY course, score DESC ";
    $result_HiScores = mysql_query($sql_HiScores);

    $sql_vehName="select  Veh_name from hc_vehicle_type where Veh_num=$varVeh ";
    $result_vehName = mysql_query($sql_vehName);
    $vehName=mysql_fetch_assoc($result_vehName);

    echo "<table><tr><th>Best Scores for ".$vehName['Veh_name']."</th> </tr></table>";
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    echo "<tr><th>Course</th><th>Score</th><th>Distance</th><th>Player</th><th>Time</th></tr>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_HiScores))
    {
        echo "<tr>";  
        echo "<td>" .$row['course'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['score'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['distance'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['User'] . "</td>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Just FYI in this code you haven't closed `<tr>`, could cause layout trouble.

Comment: To print_r: `mysql_query` will not return the result data. That is, what mysql_fetch_array (FETCH) does.

Comment: `and that mysql commands are depricated. ( I am working on that part)` ... what's wrong with a search and replace of `mysql` to `mysqli`? Would take you 5 seconds.

Comment: @scrowler and OP - use PDO.

Comment: @scrowler Converting from `mysql` to `mysqli` is not that simple. `mysqli` requires a connection argument to most functions, it's optional in `mysql`. And even if you supply it to the mysql functions, it's in a different place (last for mysql, first for mysqli).

Comment: sure, so your global replace turns into replace `mysql_query("` with `mysqli_query($link, "` and so on for `fetch` etc

Comment: @Steve thanks accidently deleted it when movig/deleting a }

Comment: @DennisZiolkowski That is only in there to see what I am getting. I thought `PRINT_R` was supposed to display the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_array` just returns *one* row of the results, not all the rows. Your `foreach` loop is just looping over the columns in the first row of results.

If you want to process all the results, you should write:

```
while ($rc = mysql_fetch_array($results_course))
```

Then inside your loop, you use `$rc['course_num']` to get the course from that row.

But I don't understand why you need that first loop at all. You're JOINing the `hc_courses` and `hc_entries` tables in the first query inside the loop. Why don't you just use that same query, but without the `c.course_num = $rc` condition, so it gets all courses at once instead of doing them one course at a time? Loop over those results, and start a new table every time the course number changes.

Here's the query for that:

```
SELECT c.course_name as course,
       e.distance as distance,
       e.score as score,
       e.time as time,
       e.user as User,
       c.course_num as course_num
FROM hc_entries e
JOIN hc_course c ON e.course=c.course_num
WHERE e.vehicle=$varVeh
ORDER BY course, score DESC
```

The PHP then looks like:

```
$last_course = null;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results_HiScores) {
    if ($row['course_num'] !== $last_course) {
        // New course number, start a new table
        if ($last_course !== null) {
            // Close out last table, if any
            echo '</table>';
        }
        $last_course = $row['course_num'];
        echo "<table><tr><th>Best Scores for ".$vehName['Veh_name']."</th> </tr></table>";
        echo "<table border='1'>";
        echo "<tr><th>Course</th><th>Score</th><th>Distance</th><th>Player</th><th>Time</th></tr>";
    }
    echo "<tr>";  
    echo "<td>" .$row['course'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['score'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['distance'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['User'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
if ($last_course !== null) {
    echo "</table>";
}
```

And you shouldn't do the `hc_vehicle_type` query inside the loop. It doesn't use any variables that change during the loop, it's just looking up the name of `$_POST['Veh_num']`. Just do it once and reuse the result inside the loop.

Comment: @Barner The join is to get the name, `hc_entries` just has the course number. I moved the `hc_vehicle_type` out as well thanks for that. Feel free to correct me on a better way, this is all new to me and ths is my first project from scratch.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to do it with just one query.

Comment: @Barner not quite right, fixed the `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results_course)){` part. I am now getting the headers, but getting undefined indexes for the `$row['course'] , $row['score']..`

Comment: I changed my answer to use `$results_HiScores`. I guess it was too much to expect you to be able to figure out that the variable in the `mysql_fetch_assoc()` call has to match the result of the correct `mysql_query()` call.

Comment: Please try _understanding_ what you're copying, instead of just copying it blindly. And if you can't understand it, you're in the wrong profession -- this is not brain surgery.

Comment: This is not a profession, simply trying to broaden my horizons.  I am trying to understand, but this is all brand new to me. I did notice that you had changed the `$results_HiScores` . My latest try is `$result_HiScores = mysql_query($sql_HiScores);

$last_course=null;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_HiScores)){
    if ($row['course_num']!==$last_course){`

Comment: And did you change `$sql_HiScores` to the new SQL I showed in my question?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40843/discussion-between-bill-flippen-and-barmar)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
foreach(mysql_fetch_array($results_course, MYSQL_ASSOC) as $rc)
{
    ....
}
```

if second argument is not given, `MYSQL_BOTH` is assumed, so array has column name, and column number 0,1...,n . so you traversed result set twice (column name and column number)

RTMF : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

and `The print_r() gives Resource ID #5 error` this is not an error!. return value of `mysql_query()` is result set. it's just a Resource of PHP internal structure.

Comment: Since he shouldn't be looping over that in the first place, the second argument is kind of irrelevant. And why would anyone call it like that anyway, when you can call `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead?

Comment: Sorry I didn't try this solution. I used Barner's above. Thanks anyways.